# Orchid plant air roots

Tags: orchids

Can someone let me know where to clip this? [image]It looks like it is growing two new plants.

Answer (score 3):

Time to grant the young ones their own territory, but **trim the roots only as necessary**.

1. **Twist** the babies off at the flower stalk. Clip them if you must. Leave the stalk for further suprises as long as it's green.
2. **Test** each baby in its new (3-4") pot to judge where you absolutely must clip the roots. Stephie suggests a twist here, and *a little loving shove is okay*. **Minimize root pruning** to minimize shock.
3. Either fill each pot with orchid bark mix and **rest it** for a day to dry the cuts. Then water. Or **first rest** the babies for a day and pot them up. Then water.
4. Either way, place your new plants in the brightest indirect light for a few weeks, or until they tell you they're ready for early-day or late-day sun (new leaves or roots). Phalaenopsis usually don't get noonday sun.

Next time you get this lucky, remove the offspring before they become young adults and scream for emancipation (their own pots). Anywhere between school-age (2 leaves) and teenage, they are ready to move on.

Comment: Twirling the plant/pot setup usually helps with getting the long roots inside without breaking or cutting anything. Think spaghetti.